# How can I count the number of parts and the frequency in every part of my signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

[image: my signal]

I have a signal like that above. How can I count how many parts there are using matlab?. We can easily count that there are 5 parts there with our eyes, but in matlab? How can I estimate the frequency of the decay in every signal?

Comment: Use `diff` and find where there are discontinuities.  As soon as you start seeing a train of zeroes, we can say that is "one" signal.

Comment: @andirkh rayryeng ment to check the diveration of your signal. Thus the change of amplitude. If there are a few zeros following each other i would even use an "epsilon" (e.g. epsilon<0.0001). This is what rayryeng called a train of zeros. If you compare your signals before a new signal starts there are a few no or at lest very small changing datapoints thus the derivation would be more or less 0.

Comment: @andirkh could you post your code for signal generation? And did you try a `fft`(fast fourier transformation)?

Comment: thanks for your help, my code for signal generation is `signal1=wavread('SARON1SL.wav');` `signal2=wavread('datauas.wav');` `finalsignal=[signal2;signal2;signal1;];` . you can download my wav audio at this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3qjch5mi0uur6w/audio.rar)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which you can modify to fit your situation.

```
%% Generating signal
x= 1:0.1:100;
xx= zeros(1,50);
xx= [x,xx];
x= [7*xx, 1.4*xx , 3*x,  4*xx, 6*x];
y= sin(x*50).*exp(-0.02*x);  %The signal i use
figure(1)
plot(y) 
y2=diff(y);  %The diveration of the signal (y(i)-y(i-1))
figure(2)
plot(y2)

%% Parameter to modify solution
epsilon = 0.005; %interval of acceptance (derivation under epsilon)
train_of_zeros = 8; %how many zeros have to be between to signals to differentiate them

%% computation
y2(abs(y2)<=epsilon)=0; %setting all points with amplitude less or equal of epsilon to nil
z=find(y2);  %finding the indices of the nonzero values.
No_Of_Signals=0; %Number of Signals
end_begin_Signal = [NaN, 0]; %help variable for saving the begin and end of signal
for k=2:1:numel(z)-1 %for all elements of z check:
   if abs(z(k+1))>=abs(z(k)+train_of_zeros) %if there are at least train of zeros between 2 non zero elements
      end_begin_Signal = [end_begin_Signal; z(k) z(k+1)]; %saving those indices
      No_Of_Signals=No_Of_Signals+1;  %plus one signal
   end
end
The_Signals = cell(No_Of_Signals+1,2); %save variable for begin and end of a signal
The_Signals(1,:)= {'Begin of Signal', 'End of Signal'};
for l=2:1:No_Of_Signals+1
   The_Signals(l,:) = {end_begin_Signal(l-1,2), end_begin_Signal(l,1)};
end
```